How to enable template_processing for Superste installed with docker?
I got installed Superset 4.0.0.
My docker-compose.yml (not full):
version: "3.7"

x-superset-image: &superset-image apache/superset:4.0.0
x-superset-env-file: &superset-env-file .env
x-superset-networks: &superset-networks
  - superset
  - clickhouse
x-superset-volumes: &superset-volumes
  - ./docker:/app/docker
  - data:/app/superset_home
  - /etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt

I add ENABLE_TEMPLATE_PROCESSING=True to docker-compose:
version: "3.7"

x-superset-image: &superset-image apache/superset:4.0.0
x-superset-env-file: &superset-env-file .env
environment:
  - ENABLE_TEMPLATE_PROCESSING=True
x-superset-networks: &superset-networks
  - superset
  - clickhouse
x-superset-volumes: &superset-volumes
  - ./docker:/app/docker
  - data:/app/superset_home
  - /etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt

Next I restart image by:
docker compose -f /opt/beget/superset/docker-compose.yml down
docker compose -f /opt/beget/superset/docker-compose.yml up -d

But I get this error:
validating /opt/beget/superset/docker-compose.yml: (user) Additional property environment is not allowed

How to add ENABLE_TEMPLATE_PROCESSING right?
Docker version 26.1.3, build b72abbb
Docker Compose version v2.27.0
Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
